Logitech Craft on bluetooth
A few years ago I found a web page describing how to connect the specific keyboard logitech craft on ubuntu.
Today it seems this page is gone.
I'm trying to connect via bluetooth. My system sees other bluetooth devices (mouses mx anywhere 2 & 2s, headphone soundblaster jam v2) and other devices (galaxy phone) can see both the system and the keyboard.
But what really is strange is the page on ask ubuntu that seem to have gone. I think it gave a link to another page giving command line instructions.
Any one has that souvenir?

This post is to say that after a reboot, the craft keyboard works properly despite I'm only only beginning to upgrade from ubuntu-mate Focal Fossa with kernel 5.40-181 généric. "Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS".
By using inxi -b I can tell wich adapter is in charge of bluetooth:
Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter.
By now, I'm gonna debug my other system before upgrading this one.

Now, I'm on 24.04 (ubuntu mate) and the logicraft works perfectly.
Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 must the interface that bluetooth comes from.
